# Color code a text column based on values in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

There are two segments which I want this macro to perform.

#### Segment 1:

Color code cells from C to S across multiple rows (I tested with 47 rows) for three conditions.

```
CELL has value between 1 & 39 = Light Green
CELL has value > 40 = Red
CELL has value = 40 = Dark Green
```

NOTE ** This segment works. Cells display the correct colors.

```vb
Sub Macro5()
    Range("C2:S47").Select
    Selection.formatconditions.Delete
    Selection.formatconditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="1", Formula2:="39"
    Selection.formatconditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    Selection.formatconditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="40"
    Selection.formatconditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Selection.formatconditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="40"
    Selection.formatconditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
End Sub
```

#### Segment 2:

I am trying to color code the person column (A) with any of the three colors mentioned above with highest precedence being RED.

- If any one cell in row in range(c to s) is red then the Person in that row should be marked in red.
- If only Green and Light green in a row Light green takes precedence and the person should be marked Light green.
- If just green in all the cells the person should be marked green.

This segment doesn't work. All the cells are highlighting in red.

```vb
Sub color_cells()
    Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r2 = Range("A2:A10")
    Set r1 = Range("C2:S47")

    For Each cell In r1
    
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
   
        If cell.Value > 40 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed Else
        If cell.Value = 40 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen Else
        If cell.Value >= 0 And cell.Value <= 39 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbCyan

nextcell:
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This is the issue when I run the above code
[image]

My expected outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your code fully qualified and avoid using select

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim formatRange As Range
        
    Set formatRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:S47") 'Change the worksheet name to the correct one
    
    With formatRange.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1", Formula2:="39"
        .Item(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="40"
        .Item(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="40"
        .Item(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

As for your 2nd segment:

```
Sub color_cells()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim cellColor As Long
    Dim capArr() As Variant
    
    Const rowStart As Long = 2
    Const rowEnd As Long = 10
    
    Const colStart As Long = 3 'C
    Const colEnd As Long = 19 'S
    
    With Sheet1 'Change the worksheet name to the correct one
        For i = rowStart To rowEnd 'Loop through your rows
            
            'Double tranpose needed to get a row of value into 1D array
            capArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(i, colStart), .Cells(i, colEnd)).Value))
                            
            cellColor = vbGreen
            For n = 1 To UBound(capArr)
                Select Case capArr(n)
                    Case 1 To 39:
                        cellColor = vbCyan
                    Case Is > 40 'Since you found a cell that's red, you can exit the loop straight away
                        cellColor = vbRed
                        Exit For
                End Select
            Next n
                                    
            .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = cellColor
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond. Appreciate it!

Comment: Please accept as answer if the solution is working, thanks! @Bellman